# Access AppEngine through Chinese Friewall

Tags: google-app-engine

We have a AppEngine application (using our custom domain name (https://www.xxxxx.de), which should be accessed from China.

We can access the website from China, when we create a Virtual IP, and point our domain name (www.xxxxxxx.de) via an DNS A record to the numeric IP address.

We can not access the the website from China, if we point our domain name via a CNAME record (as described by Google) to the ghs-vip-any-xxxx.ghs-ssl.googlehosted.com address. (The CNAME record is correct, because ee can access it from other locations with the CNAME record)

How can we fix the virtual IP address so that our A record always points to the correct numeric address?

Is there a way to determine the actual numeric IP address (on AppEngine) and use it to update our A record (which is hosted on Amazon Route 53) with a cron task?

Any other ideas?

Comment: I have asked same question to Google Enterprise Support. You cannot stabilize the virtual IP address. And I think even if you fix the A record every time it's changed, DNS resolvers cannot follow quickly.

Comment: Do you have any idea (ie experience) how often the address changes?

Comment: We had a similar problem with an App Engine application with access from China and we solve it like that: we configured the ***.appspot.com application on our domain (using the Google Apps dashboard). With this configuration some area of China starts to access to our application. To enable all the China areas we have configured and access through "Level 3" caching system, which have special contracts with China.

Comment: @RuedigerJungbeck sorry no idea, it looks stable so far. Just vip is not equivalent to reserved ip, Google doesn't guarantee it. Did you consider to use reverse proxy? That's one of the ways to avoid Great Firewall.

Comment: I considered it, but it would mean, that we need to setup an extra system just for the reverse proxy and have all the operational and scalability issues on our side. We pay for a  PaaS solution (AppEngine) to avoid having to do such things. We are considering to implement something to keep our A record in sync with Google. But this just adds more complexity on our side. And China has more than double the number of Internet users than the US.

Comment: I tried your method that changing A record by Google Cloud DNS instead of Route 53, unfortunatelly I couldn't connect from some area in china. I guess it's because the name server includes 'google' in its hostname. I wrote how to check current ip address asigned to your vip. Hope it works on Route 53

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok if you want to check which ip address is asigned, by using cron task on GAE, you need to use `socket`

```
import socket
last_ip = 'xx.xx.xx.xx' 
results = socket.getaddrinfo('ghs-vip-any-xxxx.ghs-ssl.googlehosted.com',0,0,0,0)
for result in results:
    current_ip = result[-1][0]
    if last_ip != current_ip:
         #change A record or notify someone
```

And set `cron.yaml` your desired refresh frequency.